# How to print the student name after comparing grades

Tags: java, class, oop, variables, methods

I were asked to write a class that ask the user to enter some students with their grades.
then, print the name of student who got the maximum grade.
I can do it in main method, but I were asked to write a class that compares grades. then, it returns the name of student who got the maximum grade. then call the method that compares grades in main method and print the student name.

I wrote the whole program, but I am stuck with the comparing class

```
public static String MaxGrade (int Grade[]){
    String[] StuName = new String [stuCount] ;
    int Max = Grade[0] ;
    String Name = StuName[0];

    for (int i=0; i<stuCount; i++){
        if(Grade[i] > Max){
            Name = StuName[i] ;
        }
    }
    return Name ;
}
```

when I call it in main method it, the program executes with no mistakes. but it shows null after the comparing process

```
String NameOfMaxGrade = MaxGrade(Grade) ;
System.out.println ("\nThe student who got the maximum grade is : " + NameOfMaxGrade) ;
```

I wrote a class `Student()` with its characteristics and the constructor and all the methods that my program needs to work. I just want someone to help me how to show the name of a student who got the max grade.

Best Regards,

Comment: You need to get into the habit of having your variables start with a lower case character.  example: `stuName` instead of `StuName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you collect names in your main method, the method still initializes a new student array no matter what, not using the names collected. Therefore, to fix this, you should get rid of the line

```
String[] StuName = new String [stuCount];
```

and put a StudentName instance variable (this can be a string array for example) in the class. This instance variable should be initialized somewhere in the constructor and declared outside of any methods but within the class. Because the way the MaxGrade method is written now, it's just going to return null, since the StuName array is never given any values.

```
 public class Student{
         private String[] StuName;
         public Student{
               //initialize StuName
               //rest of constructor
         }
         //rest of class
}
```

Another way you can approach the problem is by adding another parameter to the method, so that the method signature becomes

```
public static String MaxGrade (int Grade[], String StuName[])
```

so that in the main, you can enter a predefined array of student names within the method call.

Comment: thank you, I liked the second solution. that solved my problem

Comment: Although the second solution is appropriate, I would like to point out that the first solution should be considered in the context of a Class class that possibly holds a Student object array. In a student class, a StuName array does seem a bit odd.

Answer (score 2):

In your `MaxGrade` method, you create the array of student names, but you never populate with the student's actual names.

```
String[] StuName = new String [stuCount] ;
```

You need to add code that collects the names from the user and inserts them into the array.

Comment: Then please show us that code as we cannot help you unless we can see what you've done.